# meaning of dalvik VM VFY codes

Tags: android, dalvik

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of the following warnings when running my Android Application (the warnings are outputted in sequence as given):

```
04-17 15:29:11.693: I/dalvikvm(4442): DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/kirona/iclient/db/core/services/impl/MiscDatabaseModuleDaoImpl; to field Lcom/kirona/iclient/database/common/impl/AbstractDatabaseModuleDao;.logger
04-17 15:29:11.653: W/dalvikvm(4442): VFY: unable to resolve static field 30 (logger) in Lcom/kirona/iclient/db/core/services/impl/MiscDatabaseModuleDaoImpl;
04-17 15:29:11.653: D/dalvikvm(4442): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0001    
04-17 15:29:11.693: D/dalvikvm(4442): VFY: dead code 0x0046-006e in Lcom/kirona/iclient/db/core/services/impl/MiscDatabaseModuleDaoImpl;.getSequenceNextVal (Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

The application seems to run fine but I need to understand the issue since we have more complicated applications with similar errors which crash the dalvikvm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the `MiscDatabaseModuleDaoImpl` class is attempting to access the `AbstractDatabaseModuleDao.logger` field, but can't, due to access restrictions (i.e. private, protected, etc.). In this case, the sget-object opcode (opcode 0x62) that is accessing this field is replaced with one that throws a verification exception, which would likely cause a runtime crash if executed.

Additionally, the last message refers to dead code in the `MiscDatabaseModuleDaoImpl.getSequenceNextVal` method. This is harmless - it won't cause any issues during runtime. However, it wouldn't be a bad idea to find out exactly what the dead code is, and remove it. You can disassemble your application using baksmali, with the --code-offsets option, and then look at the disassembly for that method. The --code-offsets option will put a comment before each instruction containing the offset. Per the error message, the offsets from 0x46 to 0x6e are dead code. There should also be `.line` directives in the vicinity, which will be the corresponding line numbers from the original java file.

Comment: thanks for the insight. what it was is **AbstractDatabaseModuleDao** declared a private static logger, however this abstract class also extended from another abstract class that declared a protected static logger. the dalvikvm did not like this. The other consequence was some code in the **getSequenceNextVal** method called the logger. However dalvikvm replaces this code and caused it to become a dead code (I think). Simply removing the static logger declaration solved both issues. Thanks

Comment: Ah, yeah. That sounds right. When the opcode accessing the logger was replaced with one that throws a VerificationError, the code immediately following would becode dead.

Comment: @JesusFreke , Same problem getting me, I fade up this issue I,m trying since last 10 to 15 days, But I don't know how to solve. I'm getting this type of exception= ("12-30 22:40:13.202: I/dalvikvm(400): Could not find method com.anm.cms.core.util.AES128Bit.encrypt, referenced from method com.w2i.MainActivity.onCreate

Comment: @JesusFreke,12-30 22:40:13.213: D/dalvikvm(400): VFY: replacing opcode 0x77 at 0x00a6
12-30 22:40:13.232: D/dalvikvm(400): VFY: dead code 0x00a9-00d7 in Lcom/w2i/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
12-30 22:40:13.352: D/AndroidRuntime(400): Shutting down VM

Comment: @JesusFreke , Please can you tell me how to solve this issues in Android.

Comment: @tazeenmulani: if you're looking for an answer, then post a question :)